# Using fastlane screengrab for cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, fastlane

Has anyone been able to figure out how to use screengrab for cordova android apps?  I'm looking for syntax to create UI test cases in Android studio for a cordova app and I'm not finding anything.  I'm using the latest versions of cordova and fastlane.

Comment: Looking for an answer aswel. I don't think snapshot/screengrab will be of any use, because we are using an embedded webview. I've heard Ionic uses Protractor for automatic screenshotting (http://blog.ionic.io/snapshot-ionic-frameworks-fail-safe/), so this may be useful.

Comment: @VadiemJanssens - I believe I might have found a solution.  I have the code ready to test but I'm waiting on a new mac before I can completely say that it works.  I will updated with my findings when my new machine comes in.  

I was able to use Espresso Web to be able to run my test cases.  Here's a link to the example I used.  [link]https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/web/.  That will allow you access to the webview.  I also used a build-extra.gradle file to add dependencies to my gradle.build.